# What is the difference between Sonatype.Aether and Eclipse.Aether

Tags: maven, aether

Currently I am working with 'Aether'. But I am confusing which is the most suitable 'Aether' library. And which one is the most suitable for maven plugin development. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same , if you click on the github of the sonatype Aether you will see the following :

```
 DEPRECATED: This project moved to Eclipse, please follow the link below to find the new sources. http://www.eclipse.org/aether/
```

Comment: However, that link no longer works!  Is this the correct link now: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether  ?